# Is it possible to send a message from android background service to the flutter side via platform channels while the flutter app is close

Tags: android, flutter

I am new to flutter and i was wondering if it was possible to send data from my background service running in the native android part of the app to the flutter app, but while the flutter app is closed. I am curious if the flutter app would be able to get the message since it is closed  ?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter does support background operations execution communicating with the native part since latest versions, you might want to take a look at [this article](https://medium.com/flutter-io/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124).

Comment: the article confuses me, because according to the article the author had implemented background services on each specific platform, he never used flutters own

Comment: but my questions till remains, can i pass data to flutter from a specific platform while my flutter app is closed, i want to actually update the sqflite database i implement in flutter

Comment: It is actually covered in the article, he's dispatching a dart callback (that runs in background) through the native part.

Comment: the dart callback runs in the background ?

Comment: Did anyone managed to do this, the Medium post does confuses me to no end. ;(

Answer (score 0):

I show data when the app is closed by using the native layout with Broadcast receivers,  but you can save your data inside sqlite or any local database and receive this data when the user open your app by using Flutter channel.