# How do i implement platform specific notification that when clicked opens the flutter app or a particular widget in the app

Tags: flutter

I have a platform specific background service in android that shows a notification. i want it to have a functionality - when the notification is been clicked i want the flutter app to start or even better open to a particular widget, is this possible in flutter ?

Answer (score 0):

Open the app is the default behavior when a notification is tapped. To perform a specific operation when the app is open you can pass data in that notification and handle it in a root widget, to intercept it and for example navigate to a specific page in your app.

Comment: please is there any article on this for further clarification ?

Comment: Are you using local notifications or something like firebase cloud messaging?

Comment: i am using android specific notification that will be called from my android service (platform specific)

Comment: Depending on the notification you're sending the app will receive an Intent, you may want to take a look at this https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#intents

Comment: okay noted, but please can you also assist me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53460918/is-it-possible-to-send-a-message-from-android-background-service-to-the-flutter/53462215#53462215